# How can I highlight part of an equation with TikZ but without extra space around the highlighted part?

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations

I can use `TikZ` to highlight one or more terms/factors/exponents/etc. in a mathematical expression. But when I have two highlighted entities in a row extra space is introduced that I would like to eliminate, even if that means the highlighting overlaps surrounding entities a bit.

Here is a MWE that illustrates this.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\NewDocumentCommand{\hilite}{ O{brown!60} m O{rectangle} }{%
  % See https://texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/
  \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=#1,#3,anchor=base]{\ensuremath{#2}};}% previous working version
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  (\Delta s)^2 &= -(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rounded rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[ellipse] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  \hilite[orange]{\Delta\mathbf{p}}[circle] &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[yellow!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}}[rounded rectangle]\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\hilite[olive!50]{\Delta t}[rectangle] \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[cyan!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t}[ellipse] 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result. Note the extra space introduced. I would like to eliminate that.

[image: Example with extra space]

If I change my `hilite` command to

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\hilite}{ O{brown!60} m O{rectangle} }{%
  % See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406084/218142
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570789/218142
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79659/218142
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375032/218142
  \tikz[overlay,baseline=(n1.base)]{\node[fill=#1,draw,#3] (n1){\ensuremath{#2}};}%
}%
```

the result looks like this,

[image]

which introduces less space but obviously doesn't work. I've tried to understand the `overlay` option, and I understand why it causes the collapsed view here. I think the solution may lie with using `\tikzmark` but I can't seem to understand that concept. Ideally, I would like to be able to hilight any quantity, symbol, operator, etc. while in math mode. The only way I can think of to verbalize how I think the highlighting should look is that is should look like a "spotlight" centered on whatever I pass to the command, and overlapping onto other entities is okay. The shape and color of the "spotlight" can also be specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not too difficult to literally answer the question. I switch to `tikzmark` as this library is made for such things. One just need to add a node that has the desired shape underneath using the `behind path` option.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,tikzmark}

\NewDocumentCommand{\hilite}{ O{brown!60} m O{rectangle} }{%
  % See https://texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/
  \tikzmarknode[alias=n,append after command={%
  node[behind path,fill=#1,#3,overlay,fit=(n)]{}%
  }]{n}{#2}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  (\Delta s)^2 &= -(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rounded rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[ellipse] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  \hilite[orange]{\Delta\mathbf{p}}[circle] &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[yellow!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}}[rounded rectangle]\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\hilite[olive!50]{\Delta t}[rectangle] \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[cyan!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t}[ellipse] 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Almost certainly this is not what you want. It does fulfill the requirements but since the colored areas overlap with earlier elements of the equations, they erase them. This can be cured with some `atbegshi` trickery. However, I am wondering if this is what you really want. After all, fulfilling your requirements seem to imply that you highlight stuff that is outside of the node that you want to highlight.

On a different note, I'd also like to draw your attention to `\tcbhighmath` from `tcolorbox`.

**ADDENDUM**: This is the version with ship out trickery.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,tikzmark}
\newcounter{tikzhighlightnode}
\NewDocumentCommand{\hilite}{ O{brown!60} m O{rectangle} }{%
  % See https://texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/
  \stepcounter{tikzhighlightnode}%
  \tikzmarknode{highlighted-node-\number\value{tikzhighlightnode}}{#2}%
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\noexpand\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \noexpand\node[fill=#1,#3,fit=(highlighted-node-\number\value{tikzhighlightnode})]{};%
  \noexpand\end{tikzpicture}}}%
  \temp%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  (\Delta s)^2 &= -(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rounded rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[ellipse] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  \hilite[orange]{\Delta\mathbf{p}}[circle] &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[yellow!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}}[rounded rectangle]\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\hilite[olive!50]{\Delta t}[rectangle] \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[cyan!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t}[ellipse] 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. I am not a fan of the optional arguments using `\NewDocumentCommand`, at least not if I have `pgf` at my disposal. You could just have one argument, which you feed with an arbitrary number of keys.

Comment: Let me study this solution. As you say, it literally meets the specs but now I see why the earlier elements weren't showing up, whereas before that was a mystery. I didn't think about overlapping, so I've learned something. `atbegshi` seems complicated upon looking it up (I'm not even sure what shipout means). I know about `\tcbhighmath` so if there's a better way I'm open to it.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL Basically there are two options: either the fill exceeds the box that get allocated to the element you want to highlight, and you have to do something to the ship out, or you only change things within the box which is allocated to the box. You can still have ellipses and so on, but they won't cover everything.

Comment: Does that apply to `\tcbhighmath` too?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL Yes.

Comment: Setting `opacity=0.5` seems to give something pleasing. I've read about `\shipout` but I can't find an example of its application to something like this.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL I added a version using some ship out trickery.

Comment: Could you briefly explain how the trickery works?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL It makes sure that the fit nodes gets shipped out before the rest of the page. This works as long as there are not too many other macros that also use the ship out hooks.

Comment: I just discovered if I'm using `\hilite` inside an environment (e.g. `align`) that is forced to be on the next page, the highlighting doesn't happen. I think that's because the shipout only applies to the current page, correct?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL This is part of the reason, probably. I think that there is a chance that another part of the reason is the "measuring" thingy that let's the stuff inside some `amsmath` run through twice. (See e.g. [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1126#a1350) for a way to switch this one off.) I would think that in both cases the problem is fixable. One can check if the `tikzmark` exists on the current page, and then use `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` without a star. You might want to ask a new question with an explicit example in which this happens....

Comment: Thanks. Just found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/484285/218142. Is this applicable?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL I think that in principle yes, but the good news is that the updated `tikzmark` library has (improved versions of) all these checks built in.

Comment: I'm looking at the `tikzmark` docs now.