# How can I make a `tikzmark` inside an environment work over a pagebreak?

Tags: page-breaking, tikzmark, shipout

This is an extension of my previous question [How can I highlight part of an equation with TikZ but without extra space around the highlighted part?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570856/218142). The new question is, how do I make the `hilite` command work over a page break? It was suggested that the `\iftikzmarkoncurrentpage` mechanism might work, but I'm having difficulty with the required logic. I also found [Tikz picture with tikzmark across page boundary won't print if inside environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/484285/218142), [Leaving Whitespace for Hidden Text, Math, and Figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493267/218142), and some other posts that may be relevant.

I understand the difference between `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` and `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` and with the former, every highlight background is shipped out to every page rather than just the current page. I am obviously am not doing something correctly.

This MWE is the closest I've come to getting a working solution.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
%
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit,tikzmark}

% This original works, except over pagebreaks!
%\newcounter{tikzhighlightnode}
%\NewDocumentCommand{\hilite}{ O{magenta!60} m O{rectangle} }{%
%  % Code by anonymous user abcdefg
%  % See https://texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/
%  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406084/218142
%  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570858/218142
%  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570789/218142
%  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79659/218142
%  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375032/218142
%  \stepcounter{tikzhighlightnode}%
%  \tikzmarknode{highlighted-node-\number\value{tikzhighlightnode}}{#2}%
%  \edef\temp{\noexpand\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\noexpand\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
%  \noexpand\node[inner sep=1.0pt,fill=#1,#3,fit=(highlighted-node-\number\value{tikzhighlightnode})]{};%
%  \noexpand\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%  \temp%
%}%

\newcounter{tikzhighlightnode}
\NewDocumentCommand{\hilite}{ O{magenta!60} m O{rectangle} }{%
  % Modified by me.
  % See https://texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406084/218142
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570858/218142
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570789/218142
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79659/218142
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375032/218142
  \stepcounter{tikzhighlightnode}%
  \tikzmarknode{highlighted-node-\number\value{tikzhighlightnode}}{#2}%
  \iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{\thetikzhighlightnode}%
  \else
    \edef\temp{%
      \noexpand\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
        \noexpand\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
        \noexpand\node[inner sep=1.0pt,fill=#1,#3,fit=(highlighted-node-\number\value{tikzhighlightnode})]{};%
        \noexpand\end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
    }%
  \temp%
  \fi
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  (\Delta s)^2 &= -(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2} + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[brown]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[ellipse] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[cyan!50]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rounded rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  (\Delta s)^2 &= -(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rounded rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[ellipse] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^{\hilite{2}[circle]} &= \hilite[green]{-}[circle](\Delta t)^{\hilite[cyan]{2}[circle]}+
    (\Delta x)^{\hilite[orange]{2}[circle]} + (\Delta y)^{\hilite[blue!50]{2}[circle]} +
    (\Delta z)^{\hilite[violet!45]{2}[circle]}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  (\Delta s)^2 &= -(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[blue!50]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rounded rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + 
    (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[green!50]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[magenta!70]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[ellipse] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  (\Delta s)^2 &= -(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[violet!50]{-(\Delta t)^2+(\Delta x)^2}[rounded rectangle]+(\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[darkgray!50]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[purple!50]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[ellipse] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t \\
  \hilite[orange]{\Delta\mathbf{p}}[circle] &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[yellow!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}}[rounded rectangle]\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\hilite[olive!50]{\Delta t}[rectangle] \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[cyan!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t}[ellipse] \\
  \hilite{\Delta\mathbf{p}}[rectangle] &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t \\
  \hilite[orange]{\Delta\mathbf{p}}[circle] &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[yellow!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}}[rounded rectangle]\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\hilite[olive!50]{\Delta t}[rectangle] \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[cyan!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t}[ellipse] \\
  \hilite{\Delta\mathbf{p}}[rectangle] &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your strategy works. The only issue seems to be that `\iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{...}` requires the full name of the node. And you want to draw the node if the tikzmark is on the current page.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit,tikzmark}

% This original works, except over pagebreaks!
%\newcounter{tikzhighlightnode}
%\NewDocumentCommand{\hilite}{ O{magenta!60} m O{rectangle} }{%
%  % Code by anonymous user abcdefg
%  % See https://texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/
%  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406084/218142
%  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570858/218142
%  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570789/218142
%  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79659/218142
%  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375032/218142
%  \stepcounter{tikzhighlightnode}%
%  \tikzmarknode{highlighted-node-\number\value{tikzhighlightnode}}{#2}%
%  \edef\temp{\noexpand\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\noexpand\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
%  \noexpand\node[inner sep=1.0pt,fill=#1,#3,fit=(highlighted-node-\number\value{tikzhighlightnode})]{};%
%  \noexpand\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%  \temp%
%}%

\newcounter{tikzhighlightnode}
\NewDocumentCommand{\hilite}{ O{magenta!60} m O{rectangle} }{%
  % Modified by me.
  % See https://texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406084/218142
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570858/218142
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570789/218142
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79659/218142
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375032/218142
  \stepcounter{tikzhighlightnode}%
  \tikzmarknode{highlighted-node-\number\value{tikzhighlightnode}}{#2}%
  \edef\temp{%
    \noexpand\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
      \noexpand\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
      \noexpand\iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{highlighted-node-\number\value{tikzhighlightnode}}%
       \noexpand\node[inner sep=1.0pt,fill=#1,#3,fit=(highlighted-node-\number\value{tikzhighlightnode})]{};%
      \noexpand\fi
      \noexpand\end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  }%
  \temp%
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  (\Delta s)^2 &= -(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2} + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[brown]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[ellipse] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[cyan!50]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rounded rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  (\Delta s)^2 &= -(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rounded rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[ellipse] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^{\hilite{2}[circle]} &= \hilite[green]{-}[circle](\Delta t)^{\hilite[cyan]{2}[circle]}+
    (\Delta x)^{\hilite[orange]{2}[circle]} + (\Delta y)^{\hilite[blue!50]{2}[circle]} +
    (\Delta z)^{\hilite[violet!45]{2}[circle]}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  (\Delta s)^2 &= -(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[blue!50]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rounded rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + 
    (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[green!50]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[magenta!70]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[ellipse] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  (\Delta s)^2 &= -(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[violet!50]{-(\Delta t)^2+(\Delta x)^2}[rounded rectangle]+(\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[darkgray!50]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[rectangle] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 \\
  (\Delta s)^2 &= \hilite[purple!50]{-(\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2}[ellipse] + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t \\
  \hilite[orange]{\Delta\mathbf{p}}[circle] &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[yellow!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}}[rounded rectangle]\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\hilite[olive!50]{\Delta t}[rectangle] \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[cyan!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t}[ellipse] \\
  \hilite{\Delta\mathbf{p}}[rectangle] &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t \\
  \hilite[orange]{\Delta\mathbf{p}}[circle] &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[yellow!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}}[rounded rectangle]\,\Delta t \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\hilite[olive!50]{\Delta t}[rectangle] \\
  \Delta\mathbf{p} &= \hilite[cyan!50]{\mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t}[ellipse] \\
  \hilite{\Delta\mathbf{p}}[rectangle] &= \mathbf{F}_{\textnormal{net}}\,\Delta t
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Now I need to learn how to to show multiple output pages like you did.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL I use something of the sort `convert -density 300 -delay 164 -loop 0 -alpha remove file.pdf file.gif` to create an animated gif. See the end of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/).

Comment: The `\makealetter` and `\makeatother` don't seem to be needed.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL Yes, good point. (I was plaining with  `\ifmeasuring@` but this seems not to be needed.)